# What is the Best Random Card Setup Tool?

Tags: dominion, recommendations, game-accessories, game-setup

In [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-everything-organized-and-spend-less-time-setting-up) I received two different recommendations for iPhone specific apps to assist with Dominion setups.  My group uses a third (non iPhone specific).

Which is the best, and why?

Please, only one app per answer, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Zack Hiwiller's Dominion Card Randomizer is nice. It works fine on laptops and mobile devices, is free, has card images, and has some nice options.

http://www.hiwiller.com/dominion/

Downside: requires internet connection.

Answer (score 12):

**[Dominion Shuffle](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/entertainment/dominion-shuffle_ezmb.html) for Android**

I'd have to go back and use iDominion some more to compare the two, but this is the best option I've found for Android users.

- Turn various expansions on and off.
- Require or prohibit a certain card.
- You can set minimums and maximums for any number of things

  - Examples: Require at least one card each of costs 2 through 5; require three cost-5 cards; require no more than 4 cards from Intrigue; require [X] +Action/+Buy/trashing cards; etc.  If you can dream it up, you can probably do it.
- It allows you to set up a pretty detailed list of rules, like requiring a minimum number of X when any Y cards show up.

  - This lets you do the obvious reaction card(s) to go with attack cards, but you can even use it for odd preferences like: require Mine if prosperity cards are in play; require at least 4 Alchemy cards if any Alchemy cards are in play; require a Moat if a Witch is in play; require Embargo if that annoying card your friend likes is in play; etc.

Comment: It also has a good set of meta-sets. e.g. you can set up a quick rule to include a 'defense' card if there are any 'attack' cards. And those meta-sets are already defined in the App.

Comment: I wish I could Upvote this twice... Use it so much!

Answer (score 8):

[Dominion Kingdom Deck](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/dominion-kingdom-deck/id350024780?mt=8) for iPhone, free!

From the iTunes description:

> offers an optional structured randomization mode. In this mode, it guarantees that there is at least 1 card each of 2 cost, 3 cost, 4 cost and 5 cost.
>
> All current cards for Dominion, Intrigue, Seaside, Alchemy and Prosperity as well as the promo cards Black Market, Envoy and Stash are included as starting data. All sets can be turned on and off to match your playing situation.
>
> Don't like a card in the list? Swipe the row and replace it with a new one.
>
> Have a custom set? Add it in with the built-in set editor.
>
> Had a particularly interesting mix of cards? Save the list and recall it later.

Comment: And it makes playing with Black Market feasible, even with all 115 cards.

Comment: I've come to love DominionKD because you can add new expansions to it yourself, without waiting for the author to update the app!

Answer (score 5):

### [iDominion](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idominion/id351815216?mt=8)

*EDIT: iDominion has not been updated for several sets - it lacks Cornucopia and Hinterlands*

#### Features

- Turn each expansion on or off (supports all expansions through Prosperity)
- Turn each promo card (Envoy, Black Market, Stash) on or off

  - Generates the Black Market deck as well if you're using it
- Sort the resulting list by name, cost, or set (or a combination) to facilitate easy retrieval of the cards
- Randomization Options

  - Ensure Attack
  - Ensure Reaction
  - No Curses
  - No 6 Plus Cost
  - Ensure +Buy
  - Ensure +Action
- Blacklist for cards you're just sick of
- Swipe to replace any card in the set with a new one
- Correctly selects 3-5 Alchemy cards or none at all

#### Cons

- Not free (although iDominion Lite is free, and a fully functioning randomizer.  It doesn't offer the blacklist and randomization options)
- "Correct" Alchemy selection means you may have to refresh several times before it actually chooses any Alchemy cards

Comment: Worth noting that iDominion has not been updated for a long time - no Cornucopia or Hinterlands.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a solid DominionKD supporter now - it doesn't have the new sets either, but you can add them yourself.

Answer (score 4):

### [Dominion Minion](http://www.chucksmith.de/dominion-minion/) (iOS Only)

Similar to iDominion - was the first Dominion related app on the App Store.

- Enable/Disable Expansions
- Blacklist
- Change ordering - cost, alphabetical, by set
- Can only show Alchemy cards if at least 3-5 Alchemy cards

Comment: Upvoting because it supports Hinterlands.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great (the best, far and away, IMO) offline randomizer with a TON of options.  You'll love it.  disclaimer: I wrote the app :)
Get it here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gajlaijicbmdnbpdficpdlkhgajhgkkd

Not real sure why this recommendation keeps getting deleted.  I'll try one more time and if it gets deleted this time I'll appeal to admin.

Comment: Good luck, Dale! I'm just a lowly Peon myself...

Comment: Great app.  My friends and I have used it for years.  Unfortunately, it never got updated with guilds.  We're all programmers, so we just added the cards ourselves, and even offered to submit a patch to the app creator, but we never heard back from him.

Comment: Hi. I'm the developer.  I replied to your post but a bit late.  Please send me your patch and I'll update the app. Thanks!!

Comment: @Drewmate Can you contact me with your updates?

Comment: Done! I hope to see an official update soon!

Answer (score 1):

We've been pretty happy with [WebMinion](http://daaa57150.free.fr/randominion/).

It has plenty of options for how to set the cards up and lets you selectively re-randomize any of them, which we use a lot in our games if something comes up that we've seen too much or nobody likes, but we don't want to scrap the whole set.