# What is the purpose of having randomizer cards for the non-kingdom cards?

Tags: dominion

I understand having randomizers for the kingdom cards because that's how you randomly choose them, but I find it odd that there is a randomizer for every card including the basic Curses, Coins and Victory cards. Why are they there?

Comment: This question is a not quite duplicate of http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/dominion-randomizer-deck-confusion

Comment: @PatLudwig Cool, I was going to mention that.  To be honest I don't really see how they're not duplicates...? Though this question has a better and more descriptive title!

Comment: @thesunneversets - hmm, late last night it seemed there was a difference.  Rereading them, I'm less sure of that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are there to mark each pile.  The game ends when 3 piles are empty.  Once you see 3 randomizer cards showing, the game is over.

This is on page 5 of the rules:

> Players may also use the Randomizer cards as Placeholders to mark the card piles so empty piles are easily seen

The way my group lays out the Kingdom cards is organized by cost, so it is not always obvious that there is a pile missing.  The kingdom cards help remind us.

I agree with your comment that the Randomizer cards are a bit too similar to the normal cards, one solution is to put them into different colored sleeves than your regular cards.  Or perhaps, just sleeve the randomizer cards.

Comment: Thanks. It kind of makes sense, but it bugs me that the randomizers look the exact same as the normal cards when face up. Might as well use blank cards.

Comment: Alternatively, put the randomizers up side down.

Comment: Alternatively tap the randomizers (place sideways).