# Does Dominion have a collection manager application?

Tags: dominion

I was wondering if there's a collection manager for Dominion, similar to [Deckbox](https://deckbox.org/) (and many others) for MTG. I'd like to be able to add sets and promo cards I own, and prebuild (or even randomly generate) card sets to play with.

I Googled around a bit, but didn't find anything. Does an application like this exist?

Answer (score 6):

There are several apps and web pages that let you enter your sets and will generate a random assortment of Kingdoms.

One app at least, [Dominion Shuffle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nz.geek.truth.dominionshuffle), remembers your choices, so could be used as a collection manager.

[Kieran Millar's web app](https://kieranmillar.github.io/extra-recommended-sets/) serves up pre-built sets. The [source code](https://kieranmillar.github.io/extra-recommended-sets/kingdoms.js) is readily available in readable form, too, so it would be easy to duplicate the site and implement your own customs sets.

Answer (score 2):

boardgamegeek.com lets you manage your personal collection of board games in general, and this includes the ability to list each expansion and promo for Dominion that you have, including specifying the edition.

It does not do anything with generating Kingdoms. This is quite different from Magic, where building a deck out of the cards you own is a big part of what you do with playing and collecting Magic.

There are several apps and websites that allow you to generate random Kingdoms with specific conditions such as which sets to include. Many are listed in this other question: [What is the Best Random Card Setup Tool?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/355/what-is-the-best-random-card-setup-tool)